# How make Twig template display fancy Bootstrap 3 radio buttons correctly?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am running Symfony 4.2 and trying to create two Bootstrap 3 radio buttons.  Here is the HTML for what I want to create:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="inquiry[flexDates]" value="yes">YES
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="inquiry[flexDates]" value="no">NO
    </label>
</div>
```

This is my form builder code:

```
$builder
    ->add('flexDates', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => [
            'Yes' => 'yes',
            'No'  => 'no',
         ],
         'placeholder' => false,
         'required' => false,
         'empty_data' => '',
         'expanded' => true,  // these two options (expanded = true and
         'multiple' => false, // multiple = false) make it a radio button
     ])
```

I have the Bootstrap 3 theme (`bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig`) installed and have tried various combinations of `form_row()`, `form_label()` and `form_widget()`.  I've set `attr` and `label_attr` in several different ways, 
 but I cannot figure out how to generate the HTML above.  There always seem to be extra `<div>`s or HTML that causes it to display incorrectly.

The HTML is part of a hard-coded form that has been working fine and I'm trying to convert it to a Twig template.  Converting all the other fields was simple, but I've wasted nearly a day just trying to duplicate the radio buttons.

It seems like it should be easy, but how to do this is not clear from any of the documentation or examples I've been able to find.

I've tried creating my own block widget, but I can't figure out how to make the `<label>` include the `<input>` (instead of before or after).  In order to make things work, the label must wrap around the input.

There is a `{% block checkbox_radio_label %}` defined in the `bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig` file that is close to what I need, but I cannot get it to work.  It uses `{{ widget|raw }}`, but Symfony gives me a `variable "widget" does not exist` error when I try to use it.

So far, the information at https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html has been more confusing than helpful.  I've been using Twig for years and have been able to do almost anything else, but this problem has me stumped.  I know I could write my own custom filter, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

UPDATE: I was able to make things work with this ugly hack that strips out the extra tags:

```
 {% filter replace({
     '<div class="radio"><label':'<label',
     '</label></div>':'</label>',
     '<div id="inquiry_flexDates">':'',
     '</label></div>':'</label>',
     '</div>':'',
   })|raw %}
   {{ form_widget(form.flexDates, {label_attr:{class: 'btn btn-lg btn-default'}}) }}
{% endfilter %}
```

It's working for now, but there's got to be a better way...

Comment: my advise is to explicitly give it a `block_prefix` and make your own `form_widget`.

Comment: in 4.3 (https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-simpler-form-theming) this should be even easier, in <=4.2 it's still a bit annoying though and I've fought a while to manage. (https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/form/form_customization.html) doesn't help for the most generic case, but it helps in specific cases ...

Comment: the `variable "widget" does not exist` error message probably comes from your widget override, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2389d7c6868dec3f5226253c9fc87323ec0cbd86/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig#L35 , answering to a comment might cause the commenter to come back and also will suggest, that you're interested in working this out ;o)

Comment: Sorry, but I followed the link and I don't understand what comment you're referring to.  What I read did not seem to be related to this problem.

Comment: my comment. but to your point: the referenced widget shows (radio_widget and checkbox_widget), where the `widget` in the original _label comes from, but it's probably missing from your _widget. (the `{{- form_label(form, null, { widget: parent() }) -}}` line)

Comment: I've tried to use `radio_widget(form.flexDates)` but it gives me a `Unknown "radio_widget" function` error.  The `bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig` file is included in my form theme, so I don't understand what is going on.  I only seem to be able to able to the standard functions `form_row`, `form_widget` and `form_label`.  If I try to use any of other functions in the bootstrap_3 file, I get an error. 

I know the file is included, because if I change the `{% block form_row %}` definition, the changes are reflected in my form.

Comment: that's because the `form_(widget|row|label)` functions are *actual* functions defined in the twig bridge extension and are not part of vanilla twig or the templates. which makes it very difficult to extend at times. sadly. that's why I always create new form types (see answer) to manage that somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The `ChoiceType` form type is particularly nasty, because it does so much under the hood (in contrast to most other "basic" form types). It somehow turns the choices into their own form elements, depending on expanded and multiple options. Its form rendering also is quite confusing/complicated and I spend some time on rewriting and in the end I created a new form type just for my different rendering (because I honestly couldn't figure out, how to manage the `block_prefix` option).

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class MychoiceType extends ChoiceType {
   function getBlockPrefix() {
       return 'mychoice';
   }
   // find a way to set the expanded option of the ChoiceType 
   // fixed to true
}
```

in your form style (I suspect you know how to create one) you generate a new widget and label. I can't find my code right now, but hopefully the following will somewhat recreate what I once did ... there absolutely might be a more elegant way, actually overriding the form theme of bootstrap3, but ... well:

```
{% block mychoice_label %}
   {{ parent() }}
{% endblock mychoice_label %}

{% block mychoice_widget %}
   <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
   {% for child in form.children %}
       {# see checkbox_radio_label for more generic version #}
       <label class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
           <input type="radio" name="{{ id }}" value="{{ child.value }}">{{ child.label }}
       </label>
   {% endfor %}
   </div>
{% endblock mychoice_widget %}
```

this is a very specific version of the choice type, to support multiple as well, you would extend the widget of course to also support that. But I hope this will point you in the right direction. I'm not exactly sure, if the widget code has to be wrapped in something to fit into the specific form theme, but I guess you'll figure that out too ;o)

you possibly have to set the rendered flag for the child form elements. not quite certain tbh.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like I'm on a road that you've already traveled. You're certainly right about the ChoiceType. 

I've also posted a new issue on the Symfony github in hopes that some Twig gurus might have an answer.

Comment: I happened to struggle a lot when customizing forms. I even went so far and swallow default renderings `{% set dummy %}{{ form_widget(form.somefield) }}{% endset %}` just to avoid it being rendered by `form_end(form)`, then rendered it completely manually by stealing `form.somefield.vars.id` and stuff. it was really messy.